# Chaste and virgin - adjectives associated with feminine gender alone

Tags: grammaticality

Do the adjectives chaste and virgin associated only with feminine gender? Can they be extended to masculine gender or any other corresponding adjectives associated with masculine gender?

Comment: Yes, they can. You don't see the words used that way so much in older writings, because historically these traits were desirable in women particularly, but they definitely work for the masculine gender too.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422/?ref_=nv_sr_1

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a [pronounced disparity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=virgin%20bride%2C%20virgin%20groom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) in frequency of application of these terms to male and female, presumably due to a widespread double standard regarding the importance of chastity and virginity for females and for males. But there is nothing ungrammatical about applying them to what is male or masculine.

Comment: I think your specific choice of search terms tends to amplify the disparity. It's still there when comparing [**she's / he's** a virgin](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%27s+a+virgin%2Che%27s+a+virgin&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20%27s%20a%20virgin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20%27s%20a%20virgin%3B%2Cc0) (old habits die hard! :), but it's nowhere near as pronounced.

Comment: Yes, @FumbleFingers, I indeed tried that exact comparison myself first, but then posted the link to what I tried second, for three reasons: one, my example is of adjectival use, which OP specifically addressed; two, searching published books for contractions plays against the defining criterion of the corpus; and, three, it spared me the trouble of backtracking to get the URL of my first attempt.

Comment: No matter - the substance of your final sentence is probably what really counts (most Anglophones have moved on from "sexist" use of words like ***virgin***, whether literal or figurative - if indeed that was ever a significant factor).

Answer (score 0):

For a man (or for a religious person of any gender) I think it's more usual to say "celibate" rather than "chaste".

But "chaste" is also used for men, apparently – I say that only because [a dictionary example](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chaste) for "chaste" is,

> what is required of celibate Catholic clergy is to remain chaste

There is also, for example, "a chaste kiss".

Comment: But a married person can be chaste without being celibate--being duly monogamous suffices for chastity in that case. Still, chastity is sometimes used to mean total abstinence from sex, as I suspect it is in Remy de Gourmont's [wonderful crack](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Anatole_France#Misattributed), "De toutes les aberrations sexuelles, la plus singulière est peut-être encore la chasteté" ("Of all sexual aberrations, perhaps the most curious is chastity").

Comment: @BrianDonovan One can also be celibate without being chaste. The OED definition of the adjective *celibate* refers solely to the unmarried state.